# How to disable .less (dotLess CSS) syntax analysis in ReSharper 6?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, resharper, less, dotless

ReSharper 6 considers .less files as .CSS, although they aren't.

So instead of proper syntax highlighting, it underlines nearly everything with red (syntax error).

How can I disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a nice trick:

```
// /* Disabling ReSharper ;)

// .less code goes here

// */
```

It's better than disabling ReSharper for a particular set of files (ReSharper -> Options -> Settings -> Edit items to skip ...), since in this case each member of your team doesn't need to repeat this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of file types that VS tends to screw up (.haml, .less, .html, .json, etc...) and some files that you need to edit that it wont easily allow (.proj, .sln, etc...).

Best thing is to find a good text editor that you like (vim, e, textmate, notpad++, etc...) and use it along side VS.

Comment: The issue is: we use Chirp to post-process these .less files. So .css files are updated when you save .less file in VS.NET, and that's pretty inconvenient to use something else in this case.

Comment: @Garth, You are right at your point but how it's going easy with plying with 2 editor at same time. suppose in my case how VS and notepad++ work together to help me better.